# Pandas: Change subset of rows that contain duplicate values for a particular column based on values across all duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, duplicates

I'm new to Pandas and trying to understand how to modify a subset of rows that have duplicate values for a particular column, with the decision of which rows to change being made based on a conditional check across those duplicates.

Say I have a (contrived) dataframe like so:

```
    Class      Length     Head Teacher   Premium Course                       
0   Maths      Medium     Mr. Bloggs     Yes
1   English    Short      Mr. Plum       Yes
2   English    Long       Mrs. Green     Yes
3   English    Medium     Mr. Top        Yes 
4   Science    Long       Mrs. Blue      Yes    
5   Science    Long       Mr. Red        Yes
6   ...
```

Wherever there are duplicate classes I want to replace the Teacher across all the duplicates with the Head Teacher from the longest class, and remove the Premium Course value for all the duplicates that are not the longest class. If the duplicate classes are all the same length, then simply take the teacher from the first duplicate, and the opposite for the Premium Course ie.

```
    Class      Length     Head Teacher   Premium Course                       
0   Maths      Medium     Mr. Bloggs     Yes
1   English    Short      Mrs. Green     
2   English    Long       Mrs. Green     Yes
3   English    Medium     Mrs. Green      
4   Science    Long       Mrs. Blue      Yes    
5   Science    Long       Mrs. Blue
6   ...
```

In Python I would typically use loops, conditional statements etc and build a new list in memory. But I'm trying to determine the best approach in pandas.

I've been looking at the *duplicated* and *groupby* functions but have been unable to land on a solution. Any advice or help would be helpful. Trying to make the shift into thinking in a "Vectorized" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ordered [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) for `Length` column, so possible create mask by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) is for original order of rows and set `NaN`s for not matched values in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for get first non `NaN` value:

```
df['Length'] = pd.Categorical(df['Length'], 
                              categories=['Long','Medium','Short'],
                              ordered=True)

mask = df.sort_values('Length').duplicated(['Class']).sort_index()
df['Head Teacher'] = df['Head Teacher'].mask(mask).groupby(df['Class']).transform('first')
df['Premium Course'] = df['Premium Course'].mask(mask)

print (df)
     Class  Length Head Teacher Premium Course
0    Maths  Medium   Mr. Bloggs            Yes
1  English   Short   Mrs. Green            NaN
2  English    Long   Mrs. Green            Yes
3  English  Medium   Mrs. Green            NaN
4  Science    Long    Mrs. Blue            Yes
5  Science    Long    Mrs. Blue            NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Class': ['Maths', 'English', 'English', 'English', 'Science', 'Science'], 
         'Length': ['Medium', 'Short', 'Long', 'Medium', 'Long', 'Long'], 
         'Head Teacher': ['Mr. Bloggs', 'Mr. Plum', 'Mrs. Green', 'Mr. Top', 'Mrs. Blue', 'Mr. Red'], 
         'Premium Course': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

**Step1**

make condition

```
m = {'Short':0, 'Medium':1, 'Long':2}
cond = df.groupby('Class')['Length'].transform(lambda x: x.index == x.map(m).idxmax())
```

cond

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: Length, dtype: bool
```

**Step2**

edit columns

```
df['Head Teacher'] = df['Head Teacher'].where(cond).groupby(df['Class']).ffill().bfill()
df['Premium Course'] = df['Premium Course'].where(cond)
```

df

```
    Class   Length  Head Teacher    Premium Course
0   Maths   Medium  Mr. Bloggs      Yes
1   English Short   Mrs. Green      NaN
2   English Long    Mrs. Green      Yes
3   English Medium  Mrs. Green      NaN
4   Science Long    Mrs. Blue       Yes
5   Science Long    Mrs. Blue       NaN
```